# MySQL assigning value to a null alias

Tags: mysql

results table:

```
result_event | name          |  position
-------------+---------------+------------
1            | Jason Smith   |  1
1            | David Johnson |  2
1            | Randy White   |  3
1            | Billy Hansen  |  4 
2            | Wally Mann    |  1
2            | Jason Smith   |  2
2            | Billy Hansen  |  3
2            | David Johnson |  4
2            | Randy White   |  5
```

I have a table with race results as above.  I want to sort the riders by their combined placement in the two races.  (eg 1st plus 2nd = 3, 2nd plus 4th = 6, etc.)  Racer "Wally Mann" did not race the first race so even though he won the second race, he should be scored behind all others.

Desired Result:

```
Name          | Race1  | Race2
--------------+--------+-------
Jason Smith   |   1    |   2
David Johnson |   2    |   4
Billy Hansen  |   4    |   3 
Randy White   |   3    |   5
Wally Mann    |   NULL |   1
```

Current query:

```
SELECT name,
     CASE(WHEN result_event=1 then position else 0 END) Race1,
     CASE(WHEN result_event=2 then position else 0 END) Race2,
     SUM(position) eventscore
FROM results
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY eventscore DESC
```

In my current query, "Wally Mann" is first in the list because (Null + 1) < (1+2).  What can I do to make the (Null + 1) result sort AFTER all the racers who have two results?

Comment: you can try group by name, and add a condition count( * )=2, and sort them on the basis of cumulative score and then write a union query for count( * )=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ORDER BY to sort by number of records DESC and THEN BY eventscore

```
ORDER BY count(*) DESC, eventscore ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from results
group by name
order count(*) desc, sum(position);
```